# How to enable WiFi on Ubuntu server 18.04 without existing connection

Tags: networking, server, 18.04

I recently installed Ubuntu 18.04 on my device and went through setup without an internet connection. I have no access to any spare ethernet cables so it's down to WiFi. I have no pre-existing connection, so I can't install packages. At this point, I have no idea what to do. My wireless card is detected but doesn't show up in ifconfig - but ethernet and loopback do (which seems normal). I can't run iwconfig because wireless-tools was not installed, as well as wpasupplicant.
Here are some commands that give more info:

[Pastebin link to output](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/5nJH9SYRr5/)

Comment: I'm thinking I need to enable it somehow... But I don't know how.

Comment: Is this a desktop or server installation? Edit your question and show me `cat /etc/network/interfaces` and `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`.

Comment: It is a server installation. I have edited the question to show the requested information.

Comment: Is your device perhaps a laptop? Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `rfkill list all`

Comment: rfkill is not installed, and cannot be downloaded because of no existing connection.

Comment: @MIZWOZcpu your current .yaml is wrong... you still show w1p3s0, and it should be wlp3s0 (lower case L).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to edit `/etc/netplan/*.yaml` to enable your wireless card. Here's a basic .yaml for you. Note the corrected spelling of "ethernets" and "gateway4".

You'll need to install `wireless-tools` and `wpasupplicant`, so you need to either, connect your (corrected) wired ethernet connection, or download them on another machine, and put them on a flash/external drive, and install them that way. There are a number of dependencies, so you may have to obtain them also to install these. See https://packages.ubuntu.com/.

- https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/wireless-tools
- https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/wpasupplicant

You may have to adjust the .yaml, depending if you want dhcp or static addresses. Adjust the static addresses and wi-fi SSID/password as required. See https://netplan.io/examples for additional help.

Note that netplan is very fussy about indentation, spacing, and no tabs.

**For wireless dhcp addressing:**

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp2s0f1:
      addresses: [10.0.0.131/24]
      gateway4: 10.0.0.1
      nameservers
        addresses: [10.0.0.1, 8.8.4.4, 8.8.8.8]
      optional: true
  wifis:
    wlp3s0:
      dhcp4: yes
      access-points:
        "network_ssid_name":
          password: "**********"
```

**For wireless static IP:**

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp2s0f1:
      addresses: [10.0.0.131/24]
      gateway4: 10.0.0.1
      nameservers
        addresses: [10.0.0.1, 8.8.4.4, 8.8.8.8]
      optional: true
  wifis:
    wlp3s0:
      addresses: [10.0.0.132/24]
      gateway4: 10.0.0.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [10.0.0.1, 8.8.4.4, 8.8.8.8]
      access-points:
        "network_ssid_name":
          password: "**********"
```

`sudo netplan --debug generate` # make config files

`sudo netplan apply` # apply new configuration

`reboot` # reboot and verify proper operation

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95235/discussion-on-answer-by-heynnema-how-to-enable-wifi-on-ubuntu-server-18-04-witho).

Comment: Your wifi network card may be not `wlp3s0`. Use `iwconfig` to see your devices.

Comment: @luchaninov why might you think that wlp3s0 isn't correct? Check their pastebin output.

Comment: @heynnema, it depends on computer configuration. For example, mine is `wlp1s0`

Comment: @luchaninov I obtained wlp3s0 directly from the OP's data file.

Comment: @heynnema Stack Exchange is all about posting questions and answers in a format that is as general as possible.  The OP's interface is known, but mine might be different.  @luchaninov's comment is addressed to all readers.  Their suggestion to check `iwconfig` is a useful addition to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I want to thank everyone on this forum because you provided very useful information for me to figure this out.

To fix the no wifi, no internet issue with software & updates and possibly even with media servers.

I have included a file that you can just download and replace the files and information manually.

I already tested it with 13 other people and its worked for them without issues.

file is mega.nz and this is the link:

--- LINK DELETED ---

The file is 298kb since its only text files, for full transparency.

This information is on the instructions file in the zip.
If any of you are hesitant of downloading/replacing and then modifying with the zip, follow the steps below.

Open directory as administrator
Open USER LIB NETWORKMAN Folder
Open folder NetworkManager.

Copy THIS NetworkManager files, INTO /usr/lib/NetworkManager
You should have 14 files inside your own directory.

You have netplan, network and NetworkManager Folder

same concept as before, open the location /etc.
Open directory as administrator
Open /etc Folder
Open folder netplan, NetworkManager, and network. (the folder network doesnt change from what i could see in the installation, but i saw more success with replacing all of the mentioned)

Inside /etc you will replace the pre-installed files, with the new ones. DO step by step so you dont mess it up, because you must change some information as stated below.(For your convenience, since
most people are using different flavors of linux/debian/ubuntu, if you want to be safe, make a back up of your original files, and it this process does not work with you, replace the new ones with the originals)

/etc/netplan

#1. On the 00-installer-config.yaml file,
access the file and make sure you change enp3s0 for the name of your ETHERNET device.
as shown below:

```
network:
  ethernets:
    enp3s0:
      dhcp4: yes
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

#2 On the 00-installer-config-wifi.yaml WILL ADDRESS THE NO WIFI ISSUE.
access the file and make sure you change wlo1 for the name of your Wifi device.
as shown below:

```
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  wifis:
    wlo1:
      access-points:
        MywifiName123:
          password: bignasty123
      dhcp4: yes
```

If you fail to change this, then you wont fix the problem for ANY OF THE DEVICES.

/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf, here the original files that come with the installer, show managed=false. The one below, it changes the code to managed=true.

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[ifupdown]
managed=true

[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
```

3. Same location different folder , /ect/NetworkManager/system-connections/
   the file netplan-enp3s0.nmconnection, change the interface-name=enp3s0 to the name of your Ethernet device. If you have ipv6 capable device, you may change that to auto from ignore. The uuid will also be different to your device, so change that as well.

```
[connection]
id=netplan-enp3s0
uuid=6effa1b1-280b-3785-9b52-c723b445fb3e
type=ethernet
interface-name=enp3s0
timestamp=1687929716

[ethernet]
auto-negotiate=true
wake-on-lan=0

[ipv4]
method=auto

[ipv6]
addr-gen-mode=eui64
method=ignore

[proxy]
```

Same location different file /ect/NetworkManager/system-connections/netplan-enp3s0.nmconnection
netplan-wlo1-MYWIFINAME-2.0.nmconnection. Change the word wlo1 to the name of your wifi device. Do the same for the information inside that file. The uuid will also be different to your device, so change that as well. EXAMPLE BELOW: (honestly don't think the timestamp matters)

```
[connection]
id=netplan-wlo1-MywifiName
uuid=3152ed4b-995b-3833-b9d7-277f4d5c30c2
type=wifi
autoconnect=false
interface-name=wlo1
timestamp=1687929257

[wifi]
mode=infrastructure
ssid=Mywifiname

[wifi-security]
key-mgmt=wpa-psk
psk=password123

[ipv4]
method=auto

[ipv6]
addr-gen-mode=eui64
method=ignore

[proxy]
```

AFTER YOU DO THESE STEPS. Open terminal

```
sudo netplan apply
sudo systemctl
sudo ip link set enp0s3 down
sudo ip link set enp0s3 up
sudo nmcli networking off
sudo nmcli networking on

sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager
or
sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager.service

sudo nmcli networking off
sudo nmcli networking on
```

AFTER ALL THESE STEPS, YOU HAVEN'T RESTARTED, BUT YOU WANT TO TRY IF ITS WORKING? PLEASE CHANGE SET wlo1/enp3s0 TO YOUR DEVICE NAME.

```
sudo 
nmcli dev set wlo1 managed yes
sudo nmcli dev set enp3s0 managed yes
```

If all steps are completed, you may reboot
sudo reboot

once your system boots up, if you don't have internet,
terminal sudo nmcli dev set wlo1 managed yes

if you don't have ethernet,

```
sudo nmcli dev set enp3s0 managed yes
```

If you made it this far, and you still have issues, retract your steps and confirm your device id information is correct in all the files.

How do you do that?

```
nmcli
```

I suggest writing it down or copy pasting it for ease of access.

if your OS doesn't have net plan installed you may copy paste on terminal the following

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt -y install netplan.io
```

if you wish to remove it then:

```
sudo apt-get remove netplan.io
```

or:

```
sudo apt-get purge netplan.io
sudo apt-get -y purge netplan.io
sudo apt-get -y autoremove --purge netplan.io
```

THIS TOOK ME. 6 HOURS TO TROUBLE SHOOT, REBOOT, REPLACE, AND THIS WAS THE PERFECT EXECUTION
TO GET WIFI WORKING AND ETHERNET.

THIS FIXES THE NO WIFI, NO INTERNET ISSUE WITH SOFTWARE & UPDATES, UNABLE TO DOWNLOAD/UPDATE USING
GNOME-SOFTWARE, AND if your doing any VM or media server, it helps with making sure your devices are GOOD TO GO as far as operation.

Hope this works for all like it did for me.
(confirmed working for Mint, Ubuntu 19 TO 23.04, Ubuntu SERVER 20 TO 23, headless or with GUI, Arch and MATE) It's possible this might work on other flavors, but I have not tested them myself.

Comment: Flagging as spam - suspicious link, text is a rambling duplicate. All the hallmarks of a malware attack.